# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method

Tags: android, dex

I really get stuck in resolving this error when i try to use two library having common class.

```
  
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.test.orevon.realiteaugmente, PID: 9091
                  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method startCapture(Lcom/craftar/CraftARActivity;)Z in class Lcom/craftar/CraftARSDK; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.craftar.CraftARSDK' appears in /data/data/com.test.orevon.realiteaugmente/files/instant-run/dex/slice-craftar-cloud-image-recognition-sdk-android_2ef54569b311add10fb3d70edb330f83d008ee0d-classes.dex)
                      at com.test.orevon.realiteaugmente.MainActivity.onPostCreate(MainActivity.java:89)
                      at com.craftar.CraftARActivity.onCreate(CraftARActivity.java:61)
                      at com.test.orevon.realiteaugmente.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:63)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I think that this problem is related to multidex thing but i can't get the solution, i tried to add this code to my gradle file

```
    
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.orevon.realiteaugmente"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile files('libs/slider.jar')
}
```

but it doesn't resolve the problem

Comment: what are the common classes and libraries?

Comment: i try to add two jars of Augmented Reality and Image Recognition by Catchoom

Comment: and you need both the classes?

Comment: yes i need both jars but what i see it is that both library having classes in common i think that the problem came from here. am i right?

Comment: that could be the reason, i myself faced that issue in past year and resolved it by excluding the redundant class

Comment: i can't excluding classes from those jars so is there any code to add it into my gradle file to fix this problem?

Comment: try like this, not sure if it will work
"   compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.6') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }"

Comment: it doesn't work unfortunately :( but thanks  for helping ^^ i appreciate it

Comment: Does your application class `extends MultiDexApplication` or inside manifest `application` tag you have `android:name="MultiDexApplication"`?

Comment: hello, yes it's a multidex application

Comment: it works only when i delete one of those two libraries because there are classes that exist in both libraries so it works fine when i remove one library and let the other one. \n thanks for helping ^_^